# JButton variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, scope, jbutton

I am trying to code a `JButton` where when I click it, the text will change from Connect to Disconnect, however Eclipse gives me an error that says "Connect cannot be resolved." I have tried putting it outside of the try catch loop as well.

```
btnConnect = new JButton("Connect");
btnConnect.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        try {
            Connect.setText("Disconnect");
            int portNum = 5520;
            String hostAddress = Actual_IP_Address.getText();
            sock = new Socket(hostAddress, portNum);
            writeSock = new PrintWriter ( sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            readSock = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            sock = null;
        }
    }}
);
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Any pointers would be greatly appreciated."* Always be sure to ask a question. (YW). General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Factor out all the irrelevant cruft like sockets. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Connect.setText("Disconnect");` to `btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");`.

`Connect` is a class that does not exists, that's why Eclipse is giving you a warning.